# Flutter - Max number of active GestureDetectors

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, gesturedetector

I'm working on a project where I have 7 different GestureDetectors in a Stack widget. I'm trying to call onLongPress on all of them at once but after activating 5 of them, the others won't be called.

**Is anyone familiar with any limitations in Flutter on the maximum number of simultaneously active GestureDetectors?** Or might it be some limitations on the iOS and android devices. I can't find these constraints online.

For a reproducible example, I added this Widget that lays out 7 GestureDetectors. The HapticFeedback is used to check whether the onLongPress was triggered or not. When I build this to my device, the max number of clicks I can register simultaneously is 5.

```dart
    class GestureDetectors extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        double width = screenWidth / 3;
        double height = screenHeight / 3;
        return Scaffold(
            body: Wrap(
          //spacing: 5,
          //runSpacing: 5,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: height,
                width: width,
                color: Colors.cyanAccent,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: height,
                width: width,
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: height,
                width: width,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: height,
                width: width,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: height,
                width: width,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: height,
                width: width,
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: height,
                width: screenWidth,
                color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue you are facing?

Comment: most likely 5 is your touch device hard limit: try to test it with `Listener(onPointerDown: (d) => print('down ${d.pointer}'), child: Container(color: Colors.green))`

Comment: or even better call `PointerRouter#addGlobalRoute` method and try to print only `PointerDownEvent` events

Comment: Thanks, yup, seems to be the hard limit on my iPhone!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that iPhones supports a maximum 5 simultaneous touches, and cancels them all on the 6th touch.

iPad models (through Air 2), however, support 11 simultaneous touches, and do nothing on a 12th touch.

Comment: Is there a reference anywhere for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a issue of this :

**IgnorePointer** is a built-in widget in flutter which is similar to the AbsorbPointer widget, they both prevent their children's widget from pointer-events which are taping, clicking, dragging, scrolling, and hover.

Comment: Thanks Tasnuva! But isn't it weird that they are suddenly ignored after 5 clicks. If I release on Gesture, I'm then able to activate another gesture, but it's a hard limit at 5. Could specifying IgnorePointer to false be used to mitigate this?

Comment: I tried wrapping the widgets in IgnorePointer set to 'ignoring: false' but it did not have an effect. Do you know if there's a way to mitigate this?